# How to change the date format to a proper ISO date format globally in Microsoft Excel (windows)?

Tags: excel, windows, date

I want to do this globally and permanently. There is only one true date format. ISO format. YYYY-MM-DD is the one true date format. All others lead to wrong sort order.

How can I change this globally and permanently?

Comment: You can't. Excel stores dates internally as floating point numbers. BUT, how a date is displayed is another thing. That is where Number Formats come in. The Number Format you want is, "YYYY-MM-DD". But this is only for display purposes. The date is still a floating point number, and Number Formats (no matter which variation you choose) do NOT affect sorting, which already works universally according to Excel's design spec. Now, if you are using text (and not real Excel dates), then none of what I just wrote applies. It will be up to you to manipulate the text into the format you want.

Comment: Yes, just for display purposes is great.

But where can one set this globally? I know how to set it for a column or selection. I remember doing this years ago on some old version of windows.

Comment: Feel like it might have been a system wide option that excel picked up.

Comment: Not an Excel question.

Comment: That sounds like a Windows operating system question.

Comment: **ANSWERED ALREADY** See:  https://superuser.com/questions/989370/how-to-make-date-yyyy-mm-dd-iso-8601-the-default-in-excel